# ECS scheduled tasks don't execute using ASG on EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I've got an AWS ECS cluster that I would like to use run tasks every day. I have successfully created the cluster backed by an ASG on EC2 with a minimum size of 0 and maximum size of 1 since the tasks I have are short-lived and infrequent. If I manually schedule the task, it works perfectly. However, when I create a scheduled task, I see from CloudWatch metrics that all the invocations are failing.

I double-check my scheduled task and I see a warning:

```
You don't have any EC2 instances registered to your cluster. Your tasks won't be able to be run.
```

I was hoping that since I'm using an ASG, the fact that the current size of the cluster is 0 is irrelevant, it should just start one up when a task is to be executed. Is this behavior possible, or do I need to use the more expensive Fargate (granted, not that much expensive since my tasks are short lived)?

Comment: The error usually means that there is associated EC2 instances to allocate new containers. There are many things that can go wrong unfortunately. A few comon are: EC2 instance profile should be associated to the role with `sts:AssumeRole` for `ec2.amazonaws.com` prinicipal granted, and `AmazonEC2ContainerServiceforEC2Role` policy should be attached to that role, security groups should allow communicating with ECS, finally you need to have a script that echo the cluster name. Let me know if you have more specific questions regarding this.

Comment: You can also check ECS cluster events, there are some useful infromation that describes the issue may appear there.